# C# operator issues

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

Hey guys I've been getting this on some code I've been working on for school. Been googling it for hours but can't find anything, any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
if (dogName = "" || lstDogBreeds.SelectedIndex = -1)
```

Error:

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

Comment: `if (dogName = "" ||...` should be `if (dogName == "" ||...`

Comment: Change it to `dogName == "" || lstDogBreeds.SelectedIndex == -1`

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, not the equality operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) is assignment operator, [`==`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) is equality operator.

You use `=` for setting variables, like `int numberOfApples = 20;`
And you use `==` for checking if two things are equal, like

```
if (numberOfApples == 20)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the operator to compare if equal is `==`

```
if(dogName == "" || lstDogBreeds.SelectedIndex == -1)
```

Comment: I changed it to 
if (dogName = "" || lstDogBreeds.SelectedValue) 
but it still throws the same error just changing it to string and object or string and string